# How can I add map-reduce function to mongodb for reuse?

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering if there was a way you could save JavaScript functions that are used on mongodb. This way you can reuse these functions whenever you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is now a way to store JavaScript functions on the server for reuse. You just have to store them in a special collection that each database has called `system.js`. Doing it looks like this:

> db.system.js.save({
>        _id : "myAddFunction" ,
>        value : function (x, y){ return x + y; }    } );

Make sure you first select the database you want to save the function with `use <database>` command in the mongo shell.

Here is a function that I added to my system.js that checks if a collection attribute is unique:

```
db.system.js.save({
      _id : "allDifferent" ,
      value : function (collection,field) {
                 var m = function() { emit(this.field, 1); }
                 var r = function(key, emits) {
                               var n = 0; emits.forEach(function(v) { n += v; }); return n;
                         }
                 var result = db.collection.mapReduce(m, r, { out: "namecounts" });
                 var allDifferent= (db.namecounts.count( { value: { $gt: 1 } } ) == 0)
                 db.namecounts.drop();
                 return allDifferent;
              }
      });
```

In the mongo shell, you should use `db.loadServerScripts()` to load all the scripts saved in the `system.js` collection for the current database.

Once loaded, you can invoke the functions directly in the shell, as in the following example:

> allDifferent(sample_collection, name)

Also you can list the functions you have saved with

> db.system.js.distinct("_id");